# clearInterval() not working?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction(interval) {

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
        getdetails();
        $('.View').load('alert.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 3000);

    if (interval == 1) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}
```

when I call myFunction with argument 1  then `clearInterval()` not clear the `setInterval()`.I want `setInterval()` stop its excution when I call myFunction with argument 1.

Comment: Smells like something horrible in your approach. Sending Ajax request on interval is somewhere wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new timer everytime you call the function. Modify it like:

```
var intervalID = 0;
function myFunction(interval){
    if(interval == 1) {
        if(intervalID != 0) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            intervalID = 0;
        }
    }
    else if(intervalID == 0) { // create only if not existing
        intervalID = window.setInterval(function () {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the firts time you call it, it will create the timer. Afterwards when you call it with 1 as the argument, it will clear the timer.

Comment: Made a correction. Now it will create the timer only if its not existing. Previously, it created multiple timers, but cleared only the  last created timer when called with 1 as argument. Try this version.

Comment: its working only for google chrome.in mozila firefox it stop the execution of setInterval but then does not start setInterval again.